# Crop image bigger that actual image size

Tags: jquery, wordpress, crop

I want to crop the image where crop area will be bigger that image size. I am using your [rcrop plugin](https://github.com/aewebsolutions/rcrop), which is working fine.  The issue I have is that my image size is 1000x535px but I want to crop more than image size.

For example I want to crop image to 15000x12000px. In this case plugin didn't work.
I want something like [croppr.js](https://jamesooi.design/Croppr.js). Is it possible with this? The basic need is to customize the woocommerce image with custom size

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#image-1').rcrop({
    minSize: [1200, 1200],
    preserveAspectRatio: true,
    grid: true,
    preview: {
      display: true,
      size: [100, 100],
    }
  });

  var $image2 = $('#image-2'),
    $update = $('#update'),
    inputs = {
      x: $('#x'),
      y: $('#y'),
      width: $('#width'),
      height: $('#height')
    },
    fill = function() {
      var values = $image2.rcrop('getValues', inputs.width.val(), inputs.height.val(), inputs.x.val(), inputs.y.val());
      console.log(values);
      for (var coord in inputs) {
        inputs[coord].val(values[coord]);
        console.log(values[coord]);
      }
    }
  $image2.rcrop();

  $image2.on('rcrop-changed rcrop-ready', fill);

  $update.click(function() {
    $image2.rcrop('resize', inputs.width.val(), inputs.height.val(), inputs.x.val(), inputs.y.val());
    fill();
  })
});
```

Comment: Cropping means to make the image smaller without affecting it's scale. As such you can't 'crop something bigger'. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to resize/rescale the image to be larger, or to keep the image the same size but increase the effective 'canvas'?

Comment: The image quality will be terrible, if you scale a such small image up to that large proportions.

Comment: Yes you are right somehow but the code is needed for the business of wall murals. So customer can cut image accordingly for their specific size for wall murals through the website. :)

Comment: Solved -  What i did is i just started a loop with increment of +1 for number of times to  and based on that i divided the cropped size by 2. Which means if actual image is size of 1000px but i cropped the area of 2000 then it will divide the area by 2, if cropping 3000px then it will divide 3 times. By doing this i just reduced/ divided the cropper withing the actual image size.

Comment: else if(realWidth < inputWidth && realHeight < inputHeight)
                {                   for(var i = 2; i <=200; i++)
                    {
                        if(realWidth < inputWidth)
                        {
                            inputWidth = jQuery("#width").val() / i;
                            inputHeight = jQuery("#height").val() / i;
                        }
                    }
                    jQuery(".woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper .wp-post-image").rcrop('resize', inputWidth , inputHeight, m["x"], m["y"]);
                }